# URL Redirection of main domain and and Add on domain with same URL on the same host

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have one query. I am having one domain say `https://www.example.com/link-to-post` and an Add-on domain say `http://www.sample.com/link-to-post` on both of this domain have one post with the same URL. I want to redirect both of these URL to their respective post but when I open the second post that is `http://sample.com/link-to-post` it gets redirected to the first post one which I have applied 301 Redirection ie. on `https://www.example.com/link-to-redirected-post`. I want to know how can I apply the 301 redirection to the second post so that it will get redirected to  `http://www.sample.com/link-to-redirected-post` but not on to  `https://www.example.com/link-to-redirected-post`. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your .htaccess file?

Comment: I will explain you in a really simple way. I just want to redirect
`https://www.sample.com/link-to-post`   to  `https://www.sample.com/link-to-redirect-post` and `http://www.example.com/link-to-post`   to  `http://www.example.com/link-to-redirect-post` . But these both domain are on same host.

I hope now it is clear to you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.sample.com$
RewriteRule ^/link-to-post /link-to-redirect-post [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/link-to-post /link-to-redirect-post [R=301,L]
```

This checks for the hostname before redirecting to the required site. You may have to play around with the flags to suit your other needs of the site.